# Recursively Search for .git Directory From Docroot

Tags: php, git, recursion

I'm building a class in PHP for deploying via web hooks from GitLab.

Obviously the file to hook needs to be available from the web and exist within the docroot.

But in order for this to pull the repo correctly, I need to recurse upwards from the docroot and find which directory contains the .git directory.

I can't find an iterator that recurses upward.

I've tried [Recursive Directory Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php)

but that recurses down from a top level directory and that won't work since I may have several directories that may contain .git directories.

How would I go about recursing upwards until the first instance of a .git directory is found?

Comment: Recursion isn't necessary when going upwards, it simply makes it easier to go downwards.  Why not use a simple loop?  (while .git not in current directory cd up)

Comment: What would I use glob()? If not in array move up one dir?

Comment: I think `glob()` is also for searching/matching downwards.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Well ... it appears that glob() doesn't support hidden files like .git so I'll need to try another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this seems to do the trick, there may be an easier way out there but this serves the purpose pretty cleanly.

```
private function __seek() {
    $directories = array();
    $dirs        = explode('/', dirname(__FILE__));

    // remove empty first item
    array_shift($dirs);

    // remove the top/home directory as we won't be able to read it anyway
    $count = (count($dirs) - 1);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++):
        $directories[] = '/' . implode('/', $dirs);
        array_pop($dirs);
    endfor;

    $paths = array();

    foreach ($directories as $directory):
        if (in_array('.git', scandir($directory))):
            $paths['parent']    = dirname($directory);
            $paths['directory'] = basename($directory);
        endif;
    endforeach;

    return $paths;
}
```

This returns a nice array that I can gives me both the directory (parent) which I need to `chdir()` into to pull, and the directory name to pull to (directory)

```
Array
(
    [parent] => /home/solution
    [directory] => app
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me ...

as it turns out, GIT is so intuitive that it does the upstream searching for you.

I just tried to pull from 5 directories deep and it worked perfectly.

You can pull from any directory beneath your .git directory.

GIT FTW!